# Approaches to load and serve rasters dynamically with GeoServer

Tags: postgis, geoserver

I have a considerable number of rasters to serve via GeoServer. These raster are mainly representing farms not close to each other.

At the moment I'm serving them as GeoTIFF. The only problem is that so far I have to create a single store just to serve a single raster.

Mosaicking will not help, since I don't want to display all the files of separated farms at once.

I was wondering if there are any ways I can serve a raster the same way I can serve a Vector SQL View, loading via parameters.

For Example: In my Code, when a I want to serve a Vector Layer via WMS, I load some inputs like client's ID, year of the survey, etc.

Are there any ways I can serve a raster like that and manage to keep them all on the same page instead of loading raster by raster and creating store by store?

So far tried to load them with Raster2pgsql, but couldn't load more than one raster in the same table, nor create additional fields representing another foreign key attributes.

I don't know much of GeoServer so I would like to understand better how people usually handle this kind of situation.